# MVC 3 cannot convert type int to Model

Tags: c#, entity-framework

error:**cannot implicitly convert type INT? to model**
I have 2 tables in my database profile and articles... they both share a common field **profile id** when someone creates an article on my page without having a profile they receive an **profile id** of NULL, but when they create there profile i am trying to update their profileID from NULL to the current ID they get from registering a profile. I am receiving a **cannot implicitly convert type INT? to model** i have been trying new things but it keeps giving me that error

```
var oldID = (from x in db.Articles
             where a == x.RegistrationID
             select x.ProfileID).FirstOrDefault();

Article article;

var newID = (from x in db.profiles
             where a == x.registrationID
             select x.profileID).FirstOrDefault();

oldID = newID;
article = oldID;
db.Entry(article).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

The error occurs with the **article=oldID** line .

Comment: `article` is an Article object; oldID is an integer.  Of course you cannot set one to the other, why would you think you could?

Comment: well I have only been learning MVC and asp.net in general for 3 weeks now and I am learning by creating code and asking questions.. and ok i will try to cast it.

Comment: Casting would probably not help you.  This isn't MVC you're having difficulty with, it's C#.

Comment: The types of `oldID` and `newID` differ. Try replacing `var` with actual type names, it should help you (and us) identify the problem with the type conversion.

Comment: How bout article.profileid = oldie;

Comment: of course you'd need to create an instance of article first

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `Article` class (I'm guessing) which has a property called `ProfileID` is of type `int`.  When you assign the variable `article` which is of type `Article` to the variable called `oldId`, the compiler will result in a type mismatch.

Be aware that C# is a strongly typed OO programming language. You must follow Object Oriented Programming rules.

See Jeremy's and David's comments and update your question if you need more advice.

Answer (score 0):

After executing your first LINQ Expression the variable `oldID` will be getting the value of the `ProfileID` property of an `Article` instance. I guess the `ProfileID` property is some `numeric` type. article is an Instance of `Article` class. By writing `article=oldId;` you are trying to set the numertic type on a different type. That won't work !

You should probably Get the old `Article` object and set the ProfileID property value to the new value and then save.

```
var oldArticle = (from x in db.Articles
             where a == x.RegistrationID
             select x).FirstOrDefault();

var newID = (from x in db.profiles
             where a == x.registrationID
             select x.profileID).FirstOrDefault();

oldArticle.ProfileID=newID;

db.Entry(article).State = EntityState.Modified;
```